# rdl report to aspx page viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I have visual Studio 2008 web project with sql 2008 (3.5). I have created a .rdl report and want to view/post it on an aspx page. I am also using C# if that helps. What are the steps/tools needed. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to convert your rdl to an rdlc (Outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Then you can drag an aspx report viewer control to your aspx page and select the rdlc file.

EDIT: Since you already have an SSRS server, you do not need to bother converting your rdl to rdlc. I believe this is what you were looking for: [SSRS Report on ASP.NET page](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/12/tutorials/26/tutorials/4606/getting-started-with-ssrs-part-8-show-ssrs-report-in-aspnet-web-page.aspx)

Comment: Tom, I have a SSRS (SQL 2008) server that I configured and seems to work. Is there any other way to use the SSRS to view reports from the web apps. thanks for your comments.!

Comment: @FAA: My assumption was that you didn't have a reporting services server set up, which is why you wanted to host it on an aspx page. In that case, is there a particular reason you don't want to use the built-in report hosting that comes with ssrs?

Comment: No, but don't know how to use it. I just was trying it and one of the problems is when I try to view the report (from report server link), it ask for login name and password is there a way to let it view without entering the username and password. and also can I pass parameters such as date. thanks!

Comment: I just ended up given a report link from SSRS. the Above link will not work with vs 2008 (3.5) projects. thanks!